# Легкий паралакс

Tags: jquery, css, html5, css3

Добрый день, подскажите, вероятно у кого-нибудь есть на примете паралакс, только что бы он несильно ресурсоемкий был, лайт скажем так, может кроссбарузерная реализация на css.
И может есть на примете похожий плагин для реализации [эффекта](http://themes.rokaux.com/metheor/v2.0/metheor_1/index.html) как на первом экране, движение мыши приводит в действие 5 блоков с информацией.

Comment: Если нужен лёгкий пример, есть вариант на чистом css, но я бы не сказал что он сильно кроссбраузерный https://codepen.io/evolutionxbox/pen/sLvrJ

Comment: Самый лучший и нересурсоемкий паралакс - это отсутствие паралакса.

Comment: @KoVadim Полностью согласен, но речь идет все таки о его присутствии.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

По parallax эффекту:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var wHeight = $(window).height();
  
  function parallax() {
    var pHeight = $(this).outerHeight();
    var pMiddle = pHeight / 2;
    var wMiddle = wHeight / 2;
    var fromTop = $(this).offset().top;
    var scrolled = $(window).scrollTop();
    var speed = $(this).attr('data-parallax-speed');
    var rangeA = (fromTop - wHeight);
    var rangeB = (fromTop + pHeight);
    var rangeC = (fromTop - wHeight);
    var rangeD = (pMiddle + fromTop) - (wMiddle + (wMiddle / 2));
    
    if (rangeA < 0) {
      rangeA = 0;
      rangeB = wHeight
    }

    var percent = (scrolled - rangeA) / (rangeB - rangeA);
    percent = percent * 100;
    percent = percent * speed;
    percent = percent.toFixed(2);
    
    var animFromBottom = (scrolled - rangeC) / (rangeD - rangeC);
    animFromBottom = animFromBottom.toFixed(2);
    
    if (animFromBottom >= 1) {
      animFromBottom = 1;
    }

    $(this).css('background-position', 'center ' + percent + '%');
    $(this).find('.parallax-content').css('opacity', animFromBottom);
    $(this).find('.parallax-content').css('transform', 'scale(' + animFromBottom + ')');
  }
  $('.parallax').each(parallax);
  $(window).scroll(function(e) {
    $('.parallax').each(parallax);
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
height: 800px;
}
.main-slide {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  margin-bottom: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parallax main-slide" style="background: transparent url(http://duetdress.com/images/mslide.jpg) no-repeat scroll center 0% / cover ;" data-parallax-speed="-1"></div>
```

[Тут](http://duetdress.com/) можно посмотреть.

Что касается движения блоков, то я обычно использую [jParallax](http://stephen.band/jparallax/) для таких решений.

http://stephen.band/jparallax/

Comment: Спасибо за пример, меня больше интересует как отслеживать движение мыши мыши и предавать параметры translate к объектам, вероятно подскажите как это сделать, вот структура https://jsfiddle.net/antonessential/fsvq4odm/

Answer (score 4):

Вот решение для второго parallax-эффекта:

```js
 var $layerParallax = $('.layer-parallax');
 if ( ! Modernizr.touch ) {
  if ( $layerParallax.length > 0 ) {
  $layerParallax.parallax();
 }
}
```

```css
.layer-parallax {
  display:flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 800px;
  margin-top: 20vh;
}
.layer {
  background: red;
  color: white;
  float: left;
  width: 10%;
  height: 100px; 
  border: 1px solid black;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.layer:nth-child(1) {
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
.layer:nth-child(2) {
  left: 10% !important;
  z-index: 2;
}
.layer:nth-child(3) {
  left: 20% !important;
  z-index: 3;
}
.layer:nth-child(4) {
  left: 30% !important;
  z-index: 4;
}
.layer:nth-child(5) {
  left: 40% !important;
  z-index: 3;
}
.layer:nth-child(6) {
  left: 50% !important;
  z-index: 2;
}
.layer:nth-child(7) {
  left: 60% !important;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://agstudio.pro/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://agstudio.pro/js/jquery.parallax.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://agstudio.pro/js/modernizr.custom.js"></script>
<div class="row layer-parallax">
  <div class="layer" data-depth="0.25">1</div>
  <div class="layer" data-depth="0.5">2</div>
  <div class="layer" data-depth="1">3</div>
  <div class="layer" data-depth="1.5">4</div>
  <div class="layer" data-depth="1">5</div>
  <div class="layer" data-depth="0.5">6</div>
  <div class="layer" data-depth="0.25">7</div>
</div>
```

Думаю, принцип будет понятен, а остальное уже самостоятельно доработаете.

Comment: Взял ваш код копи паст, у меня не работает, транслейтов нет, почему-то родительский контейнер только двигается, да и пример здесь не работает почемуто

Comment: Пример точно [работает](https://s15.postimg.org/agdy6abx7/screen.png). Посмотрите код на вашем сайте, значения изменяются? Версия браузера последняя?

Comment: Да работает большое спасибо, то что нужно, прощу прощения, я игнорировал класс layer, по этому транслэйтился только родитель, странновато, судя по всем на этот класс в библиотеке что то прикручено.