# Скролинг фона в 2 раза медленне чем контент

Tags: html, css

Друзья, стоит задача такая, есть раздел "О нас" на сайте -> [Сайт](http://onedaytv.ru)

Мне необходимо, что бы при скролинге, в разделе "О нас" фото было не зафиксировано, как сейчас, а также прокручивалось, но намного медленнее чем сам контент. Все чего я смог добиться, это чисто его зафиксировать, как сейчас. Может ли кто то сообщить, как дополнить css для получения желаемого результата?

Comment: я не понял вопроса. все скролится хорошо

Comment: В данный момент, в разделе "О нас" скролится контент, а бэкграунд (картинка где обручальные кольца) - закреплена. background-attachment: fixed; Я хочу что бы он также скролился, вместе с контентом, НО что бы он скролился в несколько раз медленнее чем контент. Я хочу применить как бы эффект паралакса

Comment: Для того, что вам нужно - одного CSS не достаточно вроде, тут по идеи нужен ещё JS.

Comment: пускай будет, мне не принципиально, мне нужно что бы кто-то дополнил мой код, кто уже с этим сталкивался и это делал, так как я с этим сталкиваюсь впервые)

Comment: то, что вы хотите реализовать, так называемый параллакс. библиотека для реализации - parallax.js, пример - http://pixelcog.github.io/parallax.js/

Comment: То что нужно! спасибо!

Comment: [Тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/598134/%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81/598646) уже есть простое решение для Parallax